# Access parent case class from child using Monocle lens

Tags: scala, monocle-scala

I want to use optics in Scala to not go down a nested structure but rather traverse the other way around like going to Parent from Child.

```scala
case class Parent(param1: Int)
class Child(param2: Int)

val parent = Parent(param1)
val child = Child(param2)

// I would like something of this sort.
val parentParam1 = Lens[Child, Parent](_.parent)
```

I have tried creating a trait `WithParent[T]` that the child class extends. For example -

```scala
trait WithParent[T] extends scala.AnyRef with scala.Product {
  var parent: T = ???
}

case class Parent(param1: Int)
case class Child(param2: Int) extends WithParent[Parent]


object WithParentCheck extends App {
  val a = Parent(1)
  val b = Child(2)
  
  val parentParam1 = Lens[Child, Parent](_.parent)
}
```

I have 2 questions -

1. Will this method work? If so can I define parent in the trait itself?
2. Is there a better approach to this question?

Edit:

Edit 2: Account has an unique customer identifier.

Real World Scenario

```scala
case class Customer(id: String, account: Account)
case class Account(id: String, balance: Double, customerId: String)

val account = Account('01', 100, '1')
val cust = Customer('1', account)

// Accessing customer from account
val customerToAccount = Lens[Customer, Account](_.account)
```

My question: Is the reverse possible? Accessing customer from the account object?

Logic for my approach:
`trait MyParent[T]` would contain a object/variable `parent` of type T which would be accessible from the case class extending it.

Thanks!

Comment: How is even `Child` related to `Parent` or _vice versa_?

Comment: Let me update the question to give a better use case @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: Not possible AFAIK, especially because the same `Account` can be used by multiple `Customers`

Comment: Okay let me update the question once more

Comment: Then you would need some kind of store to get the `Customer` given its `id` and at that point that is not longer a lense.